# AWS DynamoDB Node.js scan- certain number of results

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I try to get first 10 items which satisfy condition from DynamoDB using lambda AWS. I was trying to use Limit parameter but it is (basis on that website)

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#scan-property

"maximum number of items to evaluate (not necessarily the number of matching items)".

How to get 10 first items which satisfy my condition?

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var db = new AWS.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {

  var params = {
    TableName: "Events", //"StreamsLambdaTable",
    ProjectionExpression: "ID, description, endDate, imagePath, locationLat, locationLon, #nm, startDate, #tp, userLimit",  //specifies the attributes you want in the scan result.
    FilterExpression: "locationLon between :lower_lon and :higher_lon and locationLat between :lower_lat and :higher_lat",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        "#nm": "name",
        "#tp": "type",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":lower_lon": {"N": event.low_lon},
        ":higher_lon": {"N": event.high_lon}, //event.high_lon}
        ":lower_lat": {"N": event.low_lat},
        ":higher_lat": {"N": event.high_lat}
    }
};

  db.scan(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err); // an error occurred
      } 
    else {
      data.Items.forEach(function(record) {
           console.log(
                record.name.S + "");
        });
        context.succeed(data.Items);


      }
  });
};
```

Comment: What have you tried? What does your code look like? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: I have no problem with my code. I just don't know how to solve that issue. Just in case I includded it in my question.

Comment: I've tried it and it evalutes first 10 items and returns less than 10 (only the ones which satisfied condition)

Comment: You either need to perform the query without a limit, and use the first 10 results and ignore the rest, or use `LastEvaluatedKey` to get more results if the first result set is less than 10.

Comment: What is more efficient? I'll propably strore thousands of items.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already know the reason behind this: the distinction that DynamoDB makes between `ScannedCount` and `Count`. As per [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html#Count),

> ScannedCount — the number of items that were queried or scanned,
>   before any filter expression was applied to the results.
>
> Count — the
>   number of items that were returned in the response.

The fix for that is documented right above this:

> For either a Query or Scan operation, DynamoDB might return a LastEvaluatedKey value if the operation did not return all matching items in the table. To get the full count of items that match, take the LastEvaluatedKey value from the previous request and use it as the ExclusiveStartKey value in the next request. Repeat this until DynamoDB no longer returns a LastEvaluatedKey value.

So, the answer to your question is: use the `LastEvaluatedKey` from DynamoDB response and `Scan` again.